# Specify the shell variant in Emacs local variables for the file

Tags: emacs, script, content-type-association

How can I specify the shell variant for a file in that file's Emacs local variables, when the file is *not* a standalone program?

Emacs allows me to specify that a shell include file should be opened in `sh` mode, by setting a local variable in the editor hints:

```config
# Local variables:
# coding: utf-8
# mode: sh
# End:
# vim: fileencoding=utf-8 filetype=bash :
```

I can specify to Vim that the file's shell variant is specifically Bash, and it obeys the editor hint to present specific Bash syntax highlighting. But Emacs has `sh` mode which covers all shell variants.

Emacs will properly interpret such a file if it has a shebang line (e.g. `#! /bin/bash`). But some files are not stand-alone programs, so I do not want those to have a shebang line.

Emacs `sh` mode treats those files as Posix shell syntax, which they are not. `sh` mode has the concept of “variant” of shell syntax; but I'm unable to find out how to specify, in the file's editor hints, which variant to use for the file.

How can I set the editor hints in the file to tell Emacs that its syntax is Bash?

*Update* 2014-04-24: I have reported [Emacs bug#17333](http://debbugs.gnu.org/17333) for this missing behaviour.

Comment: bignose's [bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17333) has been fixed. So in the next Emacs release (presumably 24.5), this really will be as easy as setting `sh-shell`
as a file-local variable. Yay! Until then, [my answer below](http://superuser.com/a/743456/66748) really does work without adding an explicit shebang line (notwithstanding bignose's initial impression to the contrary).

Comment: The fix to bugnose’s bug report appears in Emacs 25.1. The `NEWS` file states that “In sh-mode you can now use `sh-shell` as a file-local variable to specify the type of shell in use (`bash`, `csh`, etc).”

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the `sh-mode` code, it seems that someone may have intended to allow this by setting `sh-shell` or perhaps `sh-shell-file` as a file-local variable. Neither actually works, though. Please consider submitting a bug report to the `sh-mode` maintainer about this. It really seems like it should be as easy as adding `sh-shell: bash` to your file-local variables block, and that may have even been the original intent, but it just doesn’t work.

What does work is either of the following:

1. Name your file something ending in `.bash`.
2. Add `eval: (sh-set-shell "bash")` to your file-local variables block. By default Emacs will show a warning that this might be unsafe code, though that can be disabled.

Comment: The `sh-set-shell` command does the wrong thing: it *adds* a shebang line, to a file that specifically should not have one.

Comment: `sh-set-shell` only adds a shebang line when called interactively, or with a non-`nil` third argument. When called as I suggest above, it does _not_ add a shebang line. Try it and see for yourself.